# My Apple ID and phone number are being used on a new phone -- what does this mean?

Tags: iphone

I received a message that states my Apple ID and phone number are now being used for iMessage and FaceTime on a new phone. I haven't gotten a new phone, so what does this mean? The same message appeared on my IPad.

Comment: Change your AppleID password.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade iOS on any of the device(s) that you use your Apple ID on? Similarly, if you use Mac computer(s), did you recently upgrade the OS on any of them or start using iMessage/FaceTime on one of them? The message also appears when any of those occur, for some reason.

Comment: I get this every single time I login to my mac pro.  I get it every time I reboot my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

This may mean that someone is logged under your AppleID on some other phone. Change your AppleID password and security questions as soon as you can.

Changing the password will log everyone out of the AppleID, but changing the password will not allow the other iPhone back onto the AppleID.